# cannot install redis nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, redis, npm-install

```
    > sudo npm install redis 
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/redis
    npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/redis
    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/double-ended-queue
    npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/double-ended-queue
    npm ERR! error installing redis@2.2.3

    npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: double-ended-queue@'^2.1.0-0'
    npm ERR! Valid install targets:
    npm ERR! ["0.9.7","2.0.0-0","2.1.0-0"]
    npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
    npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:375:15
    npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
    npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
    npm ERR! You may report this log at:
    npm ERR!     
    npm ERR! or use
    npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/shahzad/npm-debug.log npm
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab113.11
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "redis"
    npm ERR! cwd /home/shahzad
    npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
    npm ERR! message No compatible version found: double-ended-queue@'^2.1.0-0'
    npm ERR! message Valid install targets:
    npm ERR! message ["0.9.7","2.0.0-0","2.1.0-0"]
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/shahzad/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried to install double-ended-queue on its own and that installs the 2.1.0-0 fine, but still no redis.

I have also tried: npm -rf node_modules and then ran the command still no luck.

Comment: Just installed it on Node.js 4.4.5 without problems. You should consider upgrading to a more recent version of Node.js, or installing an older version of redis.

Comment: Yeah, Node v0.6 is ancient.

Comment: Well, thats what Ubuntu's apt repository has to offer me

Comment: Ubuntu has an ancient Nodejs. Got a fresh node js with npm and it went well. Thanks.